# Mostrar números primos em um vetor em C#

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, variáveis

Meu código procura números primos em um vetor de 10 posições e exibe apenas os próprios números primos, só que o seguinte erro impede a sua execução:

> Erro CS0165: Uso de variável local não atribuída "numeroprimo"

```
using System;

namespace Vetor1
{
    class Program2
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vetor = new int[10];
            int i, posicao, numeroprimo;

            for (i = 0; i < vetor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Digite o {i}° número: ");
                vetor[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                do
                {
                    if (vetor[i] <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Digite o {i}° número: ");
                        vetor[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                } while (vetor[i] <= 0);

            }

            for (i = 0; i < vetor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (vetor[i] > 1)
                {
                    for (i = 2; i <= vetor.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (vetor[i] % i == 0)
                        {
                            numeroprimo = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (numeroprimo == 1)
                    {
                        posicao = i;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Posição {posicao}");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro em si é exatamente esse que está escrito, você precisa atribuir um valor para a variável `numeroprimo`, então deveria fazer `numeroprimo = 0`.

Tem vários outros problemas no código que não impedem o funcionamento, inclusive ele não é idiomático em C#, por isso está aprendendo fazer coisas estranhas para a maioria dos programadores C#. E não é performático. E é bastante redundante.

bem melhor assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

namespace Vetor1 {
    class Program {
        static int Main(string[] args) {
            var vetor = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++) {
                do {
                    Write($"Digite o {i}° número: ");
                    if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out vetor[i])) {
                        WriteLine("Valor inválido, tente de novo.");
                        continue;
                    }
                } while (vetor[i] < -1);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++) if (EhPrimo(vetor[i])) WriteLine($"Posição {i}");
            return 0;
        }
        public static bool EhPrimo(int numero) {
            if (numero <= 1) return false;
            if (numero == 2) return true;
            if (numero % 2 == 0) return false;
            var limite = (int)Floor(Sqrt(numero));
            for (int i = 3; i <= limite; i += 2) if (numero % i == 0) return false;
            return true;        
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EzRDVn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9IAQtc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/IsPrime.cs).

Comment: Eu não tinha percebido que você codificou, foi ver o código que postei e concertei algumas coisas e postei meu próprio código corrigido.

Comment: Aquela questão anterior minha de identificar se um elemento do vetor está vazio (sem valor digitado) ainda não entendi o que você quis dizer.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de olhar certas coisas acabei corrigindo e o código ficou assim:

```
using System;

namespace Vetor1
{
    class Program2
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vetor = new int[10];
            int i, posicao;

            for (i = 0; i < vetor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Digite o {i}° número: ");
                vetor[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                do
                {
                    if (vetor[i] <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Digite o {i}° número: ");
                        vetor[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                } while (vetor[i] <= 0);

            }

            for (i = 0; i < vetor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (vetor[i] % 2 == 1)
                {
                    posicao = i;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Número {vetor[i]} é primo e está na posição {posicao}");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```